# The math behind diagonal gift-wrapping

Tags: euclidean-geometry, recreational-mathematics

The internet contains some references to a certain method to optimize the amount of paper required to wrap a gift; namely, turning the gift box diagonally relative to the sheet of wrapping paper. See for instance ["How to Wrap a Present With Mathematical Precision" (via MentalFloss)](https://www.mentalfloss.com/article/60493/how-wrap-present-mathematical-precision-and-waste-less-paper) and ["Wrapping presents on the diagonal" (via YummyMath)](https://www.yummymath.com/2018/wrapping-presents-on-the-diagonal/) and ["Gift Wrapping Math" (via Math Encounters Blog)](https://www.mathscinotes.com/2015/11/gift-wrapping-math/).

However, in these pages details seem lacking. For instance, I would expect to see a formula for the amount of necessary paper as a function of the wrapping angle $\theta$, and then a minimization to compute the optimal angle $\theta$.

Is there a reference with a more detailed mathematical derivation of this optimality result?

Comment: I think the third link answers your question. It shows the optimal angle only. The proof that it's optimal at $45$ degree rotation should follow from symmetry and monotonicity.

Comment: @EthanBolker The third link is still far from being a complete presentation. At most it is a sketch. I have no idea what the angles are supposed to be in Figure 3b, for instance: is the larger rectangle (sheet of paper) supposed to be similar to the small one (gift to pack)? How does one prove that a sheet of paper with a different ratio cannot do better?

Comment: Also, I would have expected to find a publication by the original author of the method, not just a third-party blog entry; however I could not find one with a quick search.